# How to discard some Celery tasks when a new task/beat is triggered

Tags: python, django, task, celery

I have a celery task system requirement like below:

- Beat triggers task A every 1 minute
- Task A triggers some Task B
- Each Task B triggers some Tasks C, and run Tasks C in chain mode.
- Each Task B or C takes 2-5s (sometimes near 10s) to finish.

  - Sometimes all tasks B and C could be finished before next beat, sometimes they cannot.
- I have some other tasks (e.g. C, D) also running, which are not relevant to task A/B/C

What's the best practice to discard all the unfinished tasks B and C (without impacting C/D) when a new beat or A arrives?

My current workaround is setting different expire time for task B(e.g. 50s), and C (e.g. 40s). So that in most of cases, the overdue B/C could be discard by expire timer.

Comment: Your workaround is good, why not do that?

Comment: It's not always working. Overlap still happens when we have a long list of C. And the overlapping will cost extra CPU load.

Comment: I finally find the problem why the expire doesn't work.

Comment: I finally find the problem why the expire doesn't work.
If a chain of tasks with expire timer are sent (apply_async or delay), the expire timers are not started immediately for all the tasks. The timer is only started for the first task.
Only when a task in chain is finished, will the next task's expire time starts.
So, when a chain of tasks with expire timer setting to 40s, the execution of the tasks will last much more than 40s.